# Perform a dynamic button click when the button ids found on the form

Tags: c#, winforms, button, panels

I create a button dynamically on the form for each product like this:

```
Button btnStore = new Button();
btnStore.Text = "Store";
btnStore.Height = 30;
btnStore.Width = 80;
btnStore.Name = "btnStoreCV" + name + row[7].ToString();
btnStore.Location = new Point(ptX + 750, ptY);
btnStore.Click +=btnStore_Click;
btnStore.Visible = false;
pt.Controls.Add(btnStore);
```

Then on another button click i search the form for all the product buttons and if it finds it, I want it to perform the click event of that button.

This is what i have so far but its not working:

```
private void btnSaveCounts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Panel p in pnls)
    {
       IEnumerable<Button> Buttons = p.Controls.OfType<Button>();
       foreach (Button Button in Buttons)
       {
            if(Button.Name.Contains("CV"))
            {
               MessageBox.Show("YES");
            }
       }
    }
}
```

I have tried this aswell:

```
private void btnSaveCounts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Panel p in pnls)
    {
         IEnumerable<Button> Buttons = p.Controls.OfType<Button>();
         foreach (Button Button in Buttons)
         {
             if(Button.Name.Contains("CV"))
             {
                Button.Click += Button_Click;
                Button.PerformClick();
                //MessageBox.Show("YES");
             }
         }
    }
}

void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   StoreNumbers(0, sender);
}
```

Is there a way to perform the button's click event.

Comment: what is pt?? `pt.Controls.Add(btnStore);`

Comment: pt is a panel in the panel list pnls.

Comment: In general, why do you want to perform a button-click at all? That's an event that is triggered by the user's button-click. Normally you should call the appropriate method(s) but not trigger the event. In this case you want to call  the `StoreNumber` method for all buttons. Don't trigger events programatically if you don't have to.

Comment: It looks like you're just trying to take action based on which button was clicked.  Is there a reason you have to perform a click event to do this?

Comment: I understand you guys, Thanx, I'll try to make a method for it.